# Select2 POST AJAX Request 500 Error Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to use [select2](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) retrieving large data in my dropdown using the following [article](https://makitweb.com/loading-data-remotely-in-select2-laravel/).

> Getting 500 Internal Server Error in my console log.

I have store [token in HTML **meta** tag](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And sending a token as a parameter in my POST request.

```js
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#test" ).select2({
        ajax: { 
        url: "path/to/url",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                search: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response
            };
        }, 
        cache: true
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<select class="test" id="test" style="width:100%;"></select>
```

I have checked routes using `php artisan route:list` and clear cache using `php artisan config:cache`. But still getting the same error [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340805/14138027) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765213/14138027).

Is there anything I'm missing? I would be grateful if you can help me out to debug/inspect my Request and Response.

Tried

```
error: function(err){
   console.log(err)
}
```

Server-Side \ Controller

```
    public function getdata(Request $request){

        $search = $request->search;
        if($search == ''){
             $data = DB::table('table')
                            ->orderby('name','asc')
                            ->select('id','name')
                            ->limit(5)->get();
        }else{
             $data = DB::table('table')
                            ->orderby('name','asc')
                            ->select('id','name')
                            ->where('name', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                            ->limit(5)->get();
        }
        $response = array();
        foreach($data as $i){
            $response[] = array(
                "id"=>$i->id,
                "text"=>$i->name
            );
        }
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: active debug mode from env file and let me more details

Comment: Debugging mode is already active. I was getting Laravel error page. But this is case of AJAX request to get Dropdown data.

Comment: Can you show server-side code, error is from server side

Comment: @Maqsud check in network tab you will get more info about the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ajax post in laravel 5 return error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @KamleshPaul Giving `message: "Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist"`

Comment: add this `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your controller

Comment: I've added the following namespace `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: @KamleshPaul, `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` This is working.